# G Suite, custom domain registrar and S3 setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, web-hosting, google-workspace

I'm having a lot of trouble setting up my company hosting. I basically have 3 things:

1. My custom domain name (e.g. example.com)
2. My aws S3 buckets that contain my landing page
3. my g suite

### What works:

1. My domain name registrar DNS is setup to work with g suite and can receive mails.
2. I have 2 s3 buckets setup for static webhosting (example.com & www.example.com -> redirects to example.com). You can go to these buckets directly and it works

### What is the problem:

- I can't seem to connect all 3 of them. So S3 should be used to serve my landing page and g suite for mail, calendar, etc..

On my registrar my:

- A-records point to google: 216.239.32.21
- MX records also point to google

If I try adding a CNAME record to my DNS records to point to the bucket (e.g. www.example.com -> http://www.example.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com). Then it does serve the website but breaks mailing. If i look up the MX records it does show the s3 bucket instead of the google mail servers. So I'm kind of in an endless loop here

If someone could help me I would be eternally grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have basically the same setup except I use CloudFront instead of directly to S3, however it's a similar approach.

Your DNS records should have an A record pointing to the S3 bucket endpoint, you can see details of how to set that up [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html) You don't need to have your A record pointing to google, since you're only using their mail servers.

That same DNS record should also have MX records pointing to g suite, which seems like you already have that setup properly.

Comment: Hi Deiv, 
Thanks for your response!!

Where do I get the value for my A-records that I need to set on my registrar? I see the record sets give me an alias value -> s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com. But I can't add this as a valid A record value on my registrar.

Comment: Is it giving you an error? Are you using route53 or some other registrar?

Comment: I'm using another registrar (neostrada). But I was thinking: shouldn't I change the nameservers to use the ones R53 gives me + create the mx records in R53? Now the Nameservers are set to the ones of neostrada -> so all my mx records + A records reside there and my R53 now has 2 A records (aliases). So now Neostrada: all mx records (+ a record to point to aws?) & R53: 2 alias A records

Comment: Yes you could do that (change nameserver to point to r53), as long as you make sure your mx records and alias are in route53 then that will work too

Comment: It works!! finally :) Changing the nameservers and moving the dns records to r53 did the trick. Makes sense now, hard to see when aren't so familiar with it. Thanks a lot Deiv!!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)